# Unable to get identify CAN-H and CAN-L pinout from voltages & resistances measured at OBD-2 port

Tags: automotive, can, obd

I am trying to figure out the CAN-H and CAN-L from OBD2 port fixed below the Dashboard. I unable identify CAN-H & CAN-L as I get following inappropriate voltage & resistance values which are not as per CAN-Bus protocol.
I see only 4 cables connected in the OBD2:

- Pin 16 (Red)
- Pin 7 (White)
- Pin 4 (Dark green)
- Pin 5 (Dark Green).

[image: OBD Wiring]

Voltage between following pins(Measured When ignition ON)

- Pin 7 & Pin 16: 85 milli volt
- Pin 7 & Pin 4 : 13.98v
- Pin 7 & Pin 5 : 13.95v
- Pin 4 & Pin 16: 13.95 v
- Pin 5 & Pin 16: 13.95 v
- Pin 4 & Pin 5 : 0 milli volt

Resistance between following pins(Measured when ignition Off):

- Pin 7 & Pin 16: 100 Kilo Ohm
- Pin 7 & Pin 4 : 100 Kilo Ohm
- Pin 7 & Pin 5 : 100 Kilo Ohm
- Pin 4 & Pin 16: 83.6 Ohm
- PIn 5 & Pin 16: 83.5 Ohm
- Pin 4 & Pin 5: 1.6 Ohm

I find the above values quite strange and hence unable to identify which pins identify CAN-H and CAN-L. I don't see differential 2.5v. Also, I don't see 60 Ohm value between any 2 wires. Please clarify.

Comment: Looks like the CAN is not wired here. Pins 4 and 5 should be ground, pin 16 should be the battery (roughly +12V) and pin 7 is the K-line. Could you tell us what car it is and the year of production ?

Comment: It's an Indian vehicle. Year of production is 2015

Comment: Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All documentation out there like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics suggests that CAN is found the pins 6 and 14. Why you expect to find it on other pins, I don't know.

Instead, what you've found on pin 7 is "the K line" of an odd bus called ISO 9141-2. It's some RS232 spawn-off with semi-duplex communication on a single line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer